# How can I create one UIButton that allows me to perform 2 IBAction iOS - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

How can I create one `UIButton` that allows me to perform 2 `IBAction`. For example after a user presses "Follow" the button turns to "Unfollow" and vice a versa. Is this best to accomplish with 2 buttons or 1 button and using different states. I've research how to acomplish this with one button but haven't found any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using a single button. You need to set the title of your buttons to each of it's [states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:) and toggle the states in the `IBAction` method when a selection or de-selection occurs:

```
[yourButton setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setTitle:@"Unfollow" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

And implement the IBAction method like:

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
   sender.selected = !sender.selected;
   if (sender.selected)
   {
      // Currently selected the button and it's title is changed to unfollow
      // Do your selection action here
   }
   else
   {
      // Currently de-selected the button and it's title is changed to follow
      // Do your selection action here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I was looking for.